# How to use filter option for no fill

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know the excel VBA coding for the below scenario.

I have highlighted the cells in yellow color that matches my condition and now i want to filter the no fill cells. But, the bad part is there is no cell that doesn't matches my condition and thus there is no cells without yellow color. which doesn't show the no fill option in the filter drop down.
How can i able to get the data of those no fill cells.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change a color of one cell to empty (no color)
2. Start recording a macro
3. Select the filter for no color
4. Stop recording macro
5. Change color of cell to yellow again
6. Run recorded macro